# LAMP is working but I can't reach the local site \ site folder

Tags: server, apache2, lamp

Very new to Linux. I Installed Ubuntu 15.10 and LAMP manually via terminal commands (It seems to be working fine).

When I go to localhost the Apache welcome page appears. So I went to localhost/phpmyadmin and created an all-priviliaged user and a DB with the same name as I always do.

### The problem

I downloaded a fresh [Drupal CMS](https://www.drupal.org/) copy and extracted it's tar.gz into the 777 `var\www` folder... I changed the folder's name to be exactly the same as the PMA suer\DB name ("Benia") and then navigated with the browser to localhost\benia but I then got "Page not found".

Everything seems to be in place, what have I probably missed?

Comment: Does that mean your put your Drupal directory in `/var/www/` and named it `benia`?

Comment: That's exactly what I did...

Comment: Are you sure you have typed `localhost\benia` or `localhost/benia`? Meanwhile, can you try `localhost/benia/` or `http://localhost/benia`?

Comment: Indeed I typed localhost/benia and I also tried the variations you mentioned but none worked... All gives the same "Not found" Error ... Maybe I should move the benia (Drupal) folder from var\www to var/www/html, or check something entirely different?

Comment: Assuming its **apache2**, can you please [**edit**](http://askubuntu.com/posts/714366/edit) your post an output of `cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/default`?

Comment: Sorry I think I didn't understand - I've noticed in the tags that this is Apache2 ... Do you mean in the text?

Comment: @bnos - Well, in simple terms open a terminal window and just paste the command that I have commented above. You'll get an output. Copy and paste the whole Output which contains the document root for Apache2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33573/discussion-between-azkerm-and-benos).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a good conversation, I believe it was the root directory that you missed out to upload.

From Ubuntu 14.04 onwards, **Apache2** root defaults to `/var/www/html` not to `/var/www` as a simple **cat** the configuration file will shows.

```
cat /etc/apache/site-available/000-default.conf
```

Hope that helped!

Source: [How do I change the root directory of Apache server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23175981/2626653)

Comment: Thus, under your directions, I putted the Drupal-8-install folder under var/www/html, instead of only var/www and than it worked...